# Application stopped when if/else execute

Tags: java, android

I want to make a system where if an EditText is empty, then print a message error, and when it is'nt, then change to main activity, and print a success message. But when i press the "sig" button, the application stopped working error message appears! I need help! Here is my code:

```
Button sig = (Button) findViewById(R.id.env); // cargo el boton
    sig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            EditText nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nomb);
            String strUserName = nom.getText().toString();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strUserName))
            {
                CharSequence text2 = "¡Dejaste campos vacíos!";
                Toast error = Toast.makeText(context, text2, duration);
                error.show();
            }
            else
            {
                CharSequence text = "¡Encuesta enviada!";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);
                toast.show();
                startActivity(pas);
            }
        }

    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: "error message appears" - so what was the error message? Is there an exception in the log? (That sounds likely...)

Comment: 'if(strUserName==null){' **put your stuff for empty value** '} else {' **stuff for non-null** '}'

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with the context , so instead of using getApplicationContext() try to use class name.this in your toast method.

Comment: And what is the class name?

Comment: Like if your class name is MainActivity then use MainActivity.this like below      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , text2, duration);

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that line

```
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strUserName))
```

You can use

```
 if(nom .isEmpty())
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I did it, but "isEmpty" appears with red color, idk why! It says "cannot resolve method isEmpty()"

Comment: Or you can use if you have proble with isEmoty()
String strUserName = nom.getText().toString().trim();
if(strUserName .length()==0){
 CharSequence text2 = "¡Dejaste campos vacíos!";
                Toast error = Toast.makeText(context, text2, duration);
                error.show();
}else
do something else

Answer (score 0):

isEmpty() or null doesn't work properly with String always.
I suggest to find empty edit text in this way

```
if(editText.getText().toString().length() > 0){
//it contains something
}
```

then you can specify for example length limit here or in xml layout.

Comment: There is no error log, the app just stopped in phone.

Comment: well how you know this if statement cause the crash?

Comment: Cause i removed the if statement, and just print one message, with same context, same text and same duration, and it worked! but when i put again the if statement, it just crashes.

Comment: Or if you can tell me what is causing the crash, or how i can do that system, it would be great.

Comment: then I recommend to get length of String. instead of using TextUtils

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your time. Im so dummy, and it was a very dummy error. Here: `EditText nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nomb);` "nomb" was a TextView id, and not an EditText id, so i used "editText3", that it was the EditText id i was try to use, and it worked. I apologize and thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

i dont now what the TextUtils class validation way or check way but you can replace it with something like this

```
if(strUserName.matches(""))
            {
            }
```

this way you can check if the string empty or not